A question about the norm in the Homogeneous Sobolev space
Let $s\in\mathbb{R}$. The homogeneous Sobolev space $\dot{H}^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{u\in \mathcal{S}': \left\|u\right\|^2_{s}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\xi|^{2s}|\widehat{u}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi<\infty\right\}$
Question If $s=2$. Why $\left\|u\right\|_{2}$ is a norm if when $\left\|u\right\|_{2}=0$ then $|\xi|^{2}\widehat{u}=0$ but this implies that $u$ is a polynomial in $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ (Taylor. PDE Basic theory).
What am I misunderstanding?

This post discusses the issue of polynomial corrections to elements of this space https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372029/definition-of-homogeneous-sobolev-spaces
